# Ruby - Connect with SSL and authenticate via client certificate - sslv3 alert bad certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, certificate, faraday

I'm trying to connect a webcrawler that accesses a certain site via SSL and queries my data on that site. The authentication of this site is via a self-signed Digital Certificate. At the moment I want to access the site, I upload this certificate in .pfx format to my api, convert it to .pem, and when I try to access the site with this certificate, the response comes with status 403 (forbidden ).
However, when I try to access the site through a browser with the certificate in .pfx format I usually get it.
I already tried using Mechanize, and it worked for a while (until a few months ago it worked), but then it started to give the error:
`SSL_connect returned = 1 errno = 0 state = SSLv3 read finished A: sslv3 alert bad certificate`
The site is old, it does not receive updates frequently.
After that I already tried to use the net / http lib and the error persisted, I tried to use the httprb gem and lastly I tried with Faraday. All attempts ended either in that error quoted above or with the response status == 403.
What can I do to be able to connect? Is there something wrong with my script? Is it missing any information I need to get through?

Code:

```
# Faraday customs method:

class FaradayHttp
  def with_openssl
    system "openssl pkcs12 -in my-certificate-path -out certificate-output-path -nodes -password pass:certificate-password"

    def cert_object
      OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new File.read("certificate-output-path")
    end

    # create PKey
    def key_object
      OpenSSL::PKey.read File.read("certificate-output-path")
    end


    faraday = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://example-site.com',
    :ssl => {
      certificate: cert_object,
      private_key: key_object,
      version: :SSLv3,
      verify: false
    }
    faraday
  end
end

# Controller that try to connect with the ssl server:

agent = FaradayHttp.new.with_openssl
page = agent.get '/login_path'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# mypki will prompt you for certificates
require 'mypki'

# faraday will use certificates from mypki
require 'faraday'

faraday = Faraday::Connection.new 'https://example-site.com'
faraday.get '/login_path'
```